# In a graph, how to find the nearest node to a group of nodes?

Tags: graph, distance, minimum

I have an undirected, unweighted graph, which doesn't have to be planar. I also have a subset of graph's nodes (true subset) and I need to find a node not belonging to the subset, with minimum sum of distances to all nodes in the subset.

So far, I have implemented breath-first search starting from each node in the subset, and the intersection that occurs first is the node I am looking for. Unfortunately, it is running too slow since the graph contains a large number of nodes.

Comment: whats too slow? What language are you using? what would you like advise on? is it the speed aspect or the algorithm your using?

Answer (score 1):

An all-pair shortest path algorithm allows you to find the distance of all nodes to each other in O(V^3) time, see [Floyd-warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall_algorithm). Then summing afterwards will at least be quadratic and I believe worst case cubic as well. It's a very straightforward and not terribly fast way of doing it, but it sounds like it might be an order of magnitude faster than what you're doing right now.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the advice. In the mean time, I have realized that what I have suggested is not correct and needn't result in an optimal node. Floyd-Warshall was what I intended to avoid because of the time complexity, but it seems that it is the only correct way.

Thank you,
Nikola